# Importing External Sikuli Classes Into 1 Sikuli Script

Tags: jython, sikuli

**Background**

I am currently working on creating utility classes in Sikuli/Jython for others to use for Automation Testing creation. Right now, I am having issues with importing the Utility Sikuli files into the main Sikuli file. Are there any recommendations out there that could be helpful?

At the moment, I am trying to integrate the utility file I created into the main file. The utility will allow me to check if certain programs are opened or not by returning an integer of 0, 1, or 2. Depending on what is returned, the main file will focus them or open them as needed.

myUtilities is the Sikuli file.

utilities is the class name.

programOne is one of the definitions.

**I have tried:**

I have tried changing the import syntax and making the class in the utility file public, but the same issue comes up. I am not sure on what else to try.

**Code:**

```
from myUtilities import *

myApp = App("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Sikuli\myApp.exe")

activeCheck = utilities.programOne()

if(activeCheck == 0):
    myApp.open()
    wait(10)
else:
    myApp.focus()
```

**What I am expecting:**

The main file to be able to use the classes and their definitions from the Utility file but currently that is not working.

**What I am getting is this error:**

[error] Error caused by: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Sikuli\testClasses.sikuli\testClasses.py", line 1, in  from myUtilities import * File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli\SikuliImporter.py", line 41, in load_module return self._load_module(module_name) File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli\SikuliImporter.py", line 30, in _load_module return imp.load_module(fullname, file, pathname, desc) File "", line None SyntaxError: !!WHILE IMPORTING!! no viable alternative at input 'class' (myUtilities.py, line 1)

Answer (score 0):

your utility module has a syntax error:

no viable alternative at input 'class' (myUtilities.py, line 1)

Comment: Messed around with it a bit more, I had not correctly created the instance of the class. I now call it as: activeCheck = myUtilities.utilities() where it goes through __init__ and calls the default function like it should. Now the problem I have is it cannot compile unless I comment out the images, is there a way around this?